# MediaElement is refusing to loop

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

So I was trying to loop Background music in my UWP App, I have a class called soundControl that handles music and sounds like this:

```
public class soundControl
{
    private static MediaElement loop = new MediaElement();
    public static async void stopLoop()
    {
        loop.Stop();
    }
    public static async void loadLoopTimeBG()
    {
         Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\Sounds");
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("battle.wav");
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        loop.AutoPlay = false;
        loop.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        loop.IsLooping = true;
    }
    public static  void loopTimeBG()
    {
        loop.Play();
    }
```

And whenever I want to play this music I call :

```
soundControl.loadLoopTimeBG();    
soundControl.loopTimeBG();
```

the problem is the it plays just one time and stops and I have no Idea why
I tried another approach like:

```
loop.MediaEnded += mediaEnded;
```

and the event handler like this:

```
    private static void mediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loop.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        loop.Play();
    }
```

it also didn't work and when debugging it doesn't even triger the mediaEnded event when music is complete.

Any help here would be most appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `MediaPlayer`

`Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer` is the [recommended player for UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource)  that does not require to be in the XAML visual tree.

Its API is very similar to `MediaElement`:

```
private static MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

public static async Task PlayUsingMediaPlayerAsync()
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Click.wav");
    _mediaPlayer.AutoPlay = false;
    _mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);

    _mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += _mediaPlayer_MediaOpened;

    _mediaPlayer.IsLoopingEnabled = true;

}

private static void _mediaPlayer_MediaOpened(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    sender.Play();
}
```

You can even display the visuals of a `MediaPlayer` in XAML using `MediaPlayerElement`.

`MediaPlayer` allows for even more advanced playback scenarios using the `MediaPlaybackList` with support for looping, shuffle and gapless playback.

```
mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlaybackList);
```

## `MediaElement`

After some digging around it seems that there are two issues.

`MediaElement` is XAML based control (in the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` namespace), and it seems that it does not work properly until it is actually attached to a visual tree. Once you put the `MediaElement` on the page, it works as expected.

Secondly, loading source media does not happen immediately. Once you set the source, the control needs some time to actually load the media. For this purpose, you can use the `MediaOpened` event, that will notify you once it is really loaded.

So the code could look somewhat like this:

```
public static async Task LoadAndPlayAsync()
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Click.wav");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    loop.AutoPlay = false;
    loop.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    //or simpler -
    //loop.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Click.wav", UriKind.Absolute);
    loop.MediaOpened += Loop_MediaOpened;
    loop.IsLooping = true;
}

private static void Loop_MediaOpened(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //play once the media is actually ready
    loop.Play();
}
```

And before you call the `LoadAndPlayAsync` method, you have to attach the control somewhere (for example in a `Grid`):

```
GridContainer.Children.Add(SoundController.loop);
await SoundController.LoadAndPlayAsync();
```

I have created a [sample project for my tests on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/LoopingMediaElement), you can check it out to see how I implemented it. The first button in the app attaches the control and the second loads and plays the sound. You can see that if you click only the second one, the sound does not play.

Comment: thanks for the answer but still no luck with this it was already saved with Audacity as wav,  tried your suggestion to save it as MP3 still same problem.
What I noticed was if I create the mediaElement in xaml rather than in the code it will start behaving as it should.
I just want to see if anyone understand why is this the case cause I'm really curious right now.

Comment: I have updated my answer with my findings :-) . This is really a very interesting problem

Comment: Welll well this is a very interesting explanation it actually does work once I add it to a canvas thank you very much , this problem intrigued me so much that even when I found a workaround I wasn't satisfied.

Comment: And I have updated the answer once again with the information about `MediaPlayer` class, which seems to be the recommended solution when you don't want to add the element into XAML tree :-)

Comment: If you find a way to overcome the delay between loops in `MediaPlayer` let me know please, I would be really interested :-O .

Comment: I have found the way to allow gapless playback using `MediaPlayer` so I have updated the answer once more :-). According to Microsoft, `MediaPlayer` is the recommended player going forward :-)

Comment: yep actually I did Try both and what I found was two things,1)MediaPlayer preforms better for click sounds in MediaElement you will get some Airy clicks once in a while , 2)to make MediaPlayer Work your app needs to target Windows Aniversary else you will get an error that there is no such constructor new MediaPlayer(), and that causes the app not to run on lower versions which I'm not sure its a good thing for now.

Comment: Having to target just Anniversary update is a little disadvantage, but it is not the worst thing - majority of users have been updated to Anniversary update - around 80 %